# extra characters when scrolling through command history in bash

Tags: bash

When I use the up arrow key to scroll through my command history in bash, I'm frequently, but not always, ending up with the first three characters of the command getting stuck essentially.

For example, I type the following commands (in this order):

```
>whoami
>pwd
>ls -la
```

Now I hit up once and get:

```
>ls -la
```

I hit it a second time and get

```
>ls pwd
```

I hit it an third time and get

```
>ls whoami
```

If I then hit down a couple times, I get

```
>ls ls -la
```

and if I go all the way down i just get

```
>ls
```

If I hit enter here, it does behave as if there's nothing there (rather than the extra ls)

What could be causing this/where should I be looking?  I'm still mostly a linux newb.

Comment: My guess is that you aren't "getting" those commands – it's just printing them offset by three characters, and the `ls` never gets overwritten.

Comment: Do you have some funny non-printing characters in your prompt that are confusing bash?  `echo $PS1` for us.

Comment: Check your `~/.inputrc` for any corruptions.

Comment: Yeah, I started playing around with my $PS1 and that seemed to be the problem...
The issue was with a \n within color markers

Comment: @CarlNorum Good catch, can you please post that as an answer so that it becomes a good reference point for others in agony. :)

Comment: Looks like gusto answered it himself.  That's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. The problem was with the location of a \n in my PS1 prompt.

The bad version:

```
export PS1="\n\e[0;33m[\!]\e[m\e[0;32m[\A \w]\n\e[m>
```

The good version:

```
export PS1="\n\e[0;33m[\!]\e[m\e[0;32m[\A \w]\e[m\n>
```